# Button Tap Event not recognized with RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, event-handling, rx-swift, reactive-swift

I have a `UIViewController` subclass with 3 buttons. After 3 taps on button "continue", I pop this view controller from my navigation stack and push another instance of the same class. However, when I have this new view controller object pushed, I don't receive the `rx.tap` events. After putting `.debug()`on these subscriptions and a `print(#function)` on the `deinit()` of my view controller I get the following logs:

[image: Log]

I seems that the program is can't distinguish the buttons from the two instances of my view controller and thus subscribing for the second time before they are disposed.

Can someone help me fix this issue? 
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Here is how I subscribe to the button taps:

```
self.backButton.rx.tap
            .debug("back button")
            .bind(to: self.viewModel.backButtonPressed)
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code where you're subscripting to button taps?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the `completed` event from the continue is shutting down whatever is subscribed to it so when the second continue button subscribes to it the next events from it are being ignored.